# Nginx Different Domains on Same IP

Tags: nginx, dns

I would like to host 2 different domains in the same server using Nginx.
I redirected both domains to this host via @ property. Although I configure 2 different server blocks, whenever I try to access second domain, it redirects to first one.

Here is my config.

```
server {
    listen      `www.domain1.example:80`;
    access_log  `/var/log/nginx/host.domain1.access.log`  main;
    root `/var/www/domain1`;
    server_name `www.domain1.example`;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        # Security: must set cgi.fixpathinfo to 0 in `php.ini`!
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass `127.0.0.1:9000`;
        fastcgi_index `index.php`;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME         $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        include `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params`;
    }
}

server {
    listen       www.domain2.example:80;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.domain2.access.log  main;
    root /var/www/domain2;
    server_name www.domain2.example;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        # Security: must set cgi.fixpathinfo to 0 in php.ini!
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME         $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 186, accepted):

Your "listen" directives are wrong. See this page: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html.

They should be

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name www.domain1.example;
    root /var/www/domain1;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name www.domain2.example;
    root /var/www/domain2;
}
```

Note, I have only included the relevant lines. Everything else looked okay but I just deleted it for clarity. To test it you might want to try serving a text file from each server first before actually serving PHP. That's why I left the 'root' directive in there.

Comment: This fixed it for me. The problem seems to have been that in both of my `server {}` blocks, the sever_name directives were wildcards: `.domain1.com` and `.domain2.com`. Changing them to `server_name www.domain1.com domain1.com;` and `server_name www.domain2.com domain2.com;` now has the correct page for each site displaying when those addresses are used.

Comment: I know this is dredging up an ancient comment.  But I assume that these two server blocks could be in separate config files in sites-enabled/ ?

Comment: Absolutely, it just depends on how you want to structure your config. I tend to have one file per real domain. Each of which might contain multiple server blocks.

Comment: I highly recommend to add the "www" cases also like the comment of Steve HHH, in my case I had only configured domain1.com and domain2.com, in Desktop Browsers it worked perfectly, but in the iPhone, the Browser adds "www" always, so www.domain1.com and www.domain2.com display the default site, in my case was domain1.com app for both options as "www" cases were not configured correctly.

Comment: You REALLY don't want to do that. Pick either www.domain.com or domain.com and redirect one to the other. Having the same content at two different addresses is seen as spammy and can heavily damage your search ranking.

Comment: its really important to add www in server_name www.domain2.com; I was not clear on this one

Comment: You can also just use `.domain.com`. It's a special nginx wildcard that matches `domain.com` and `*.domain.com`. See: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: u helped me to save my time ,tnx buddy.

Comment: This doesn't work for me under windows and host names defined in the hosts file. Requests to the second domain lands to the `root` of the fisrt domain.

Comment: I have zero knowledge of using nginx under windows sorry. You might want to ask a new question. Give details of your setup. And post both your hosts file and your nginx config.