# Run two different django-cms applications with different domains on the same ip on nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx, dns, django-cms

I want two host two different django-cms applications with different domains on one server with the same ip adress running nginx.

I already found this related question, howewer I could not translate the solution to my python applications: [Nginx Different Domains on Same IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773544/nginx-different-domains-on-same-ip)

I am already running the first django-cms application using uwsgi on port 7000 and serve it through nginx.

Now I would like to add a second django-cms apllication also using uwsgi on port 9000 for a different domain to my current nginx config.

I tried to add the second uwsgi application to the upstream app_servers section in nginx but this did not work and caused an error.

Here is my current nginx configuration:

```
worker_processes 1;

events {

    worker_connections 1024;

}

http {

    types_hash_max_size 2048;   
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    sendfile on;

    gzip              on;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_proxied      any;
    gzip_min_length   500;
    gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_types        text/plain text/xml text/css
                      text/comma-separated-values
                      text/javascript
                      application/x-javascript
                      application/atom+xml;

    # Configuration containing list of application servers
    upstream app_servers {

        server 127.0.0.1:7000;
        #server 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # ..
        # .

    }

    # Configuration for Nginx
    server {

        # Running port
        listen 80;
    server_name www.myfirstdomain.at;

        # Settings to serve static files 
        location ^~ /static/  {

            # Example:
            # root /full/path/to/application/static/file/dir;
            alias /webapps/first-django-cms-app/static/;

        }

        # Serve a static file (ex. favico)
        # outside /static directory
        location = /favico.ico  {

            root /app/favico.ico;

        }

        # Proxy connections to the application servers
        # app_servers
        location / {

            include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;        
            proxy_pass         http://app_servers;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

        }
    }
}
```

How could I change my nginx configuration to make this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two `server`-sections with different server-names and two `upstream` sections with different names e.g. `app_server_1` and `app_server_2`.

Comment: that was exactly what I was looking for, thank you. Just for completion I also had to add this line in the http section of my config: server_names_hash_bucket_size 64; And the upstream app_servername has to be set in the server location proxy pass attribute: http://app_server1;

Comment: is any solution for this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63148739/running-multiple-django-project-on-same-ubuntu-instance-using-nginx-as-a-proxy-s