# Running multiple django project on same ubuntu instance using nginx as a proxy server, nginx is forwarding some requests from one domain to wrong port

Tags: django, nginx, nginx-location

I want to run three subdomains on the same server and the same service in a different folder all this are Django service.

bellow is the Nginx conf file

I am trying to run request-micro service on the same server with a different domains and different folders.

I am already running two test server domain on 2732 port in "home/user/test/" folder and its running fine,

Now I am trying to run dev server on 2742 port in different directory "/home/user/dev/" but some times the test server requests are coming on dev server ports.it should be on 2732.

**test.buyer1.domain.co should redirect to 2732 and dev.buyer2.domain.co should redirect to 2742 port but sometimes test.buyer1.domain.co redirects to 2742.**

how can I differentiate dev and test server?

```
server {
        server_name  test.buyer1.domain.co ;
        location /request-micro {
                allow all;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2732;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                client_max_body_size 2000M;
                alias /home/ubuntu/test/project/project;
        }
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.buyer1.domain.co/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.buyer1.domain.co/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
        server_name  test.buyer2.domain.co ;
        location /request-micro {
                allow all;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2732;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                client_max_body_size 2000M;
                alias /home/ubuntu/test/project/project;
        }
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.buyer2.domain.co/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.buyer2.domain.co/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
        server_name  dev.buyer2.domain.co ;
        location /request-micro {
                allow all;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2742;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                client_max_body_size 2000M;
                alias /home/ubuntu/dev/project/project;
        }
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.buyer2.domain.co/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.buyer2.domain.co/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = test.buyer1.domain.co) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        server_name  test.buyer1.domain.co ;
        listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = test.buyer2.domain.co) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        server_name  test.buyer2.domain.co ;
        listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = dev.buyer2.domain.co) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        server_name  dev.buyer2.domain.co ;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

what should I do?