# AWS: can I map ports to static ips?

Tags: amazon-web-services, port

I have free tier of AWS for testing. I want to host five websites for five different domains on one VM. I understand that I need five static ip addresses for A-name. And I not found that in AWS I can map, for example, port 81 to 11.11.11.11 and port 82 to 22.22.22.22 - because for A-name we can't set ip with port, for example 11.11.11.11:81

Now I can map to my VM (to one static ip) only one domain - how can I host another four sites at one VM? This is possible?

Comment: Map all your A record in route 53 to a single IP for your EC2 instance and handle the server names in different web server configurations. You can host as many as you want on a box (assuming the box can handle the load)

Comment: Can you please show the example of such kind handling for Apache? How I can google it? This technique not bad for speed of loading?

Comment: As I say, depends on how many you have versus the box specs. It's a common process that many cheap hosting companies use. Google multiple vhosts on EC2 instance, I'm sure I've seen and answered a question like this on StackOverflow before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for help - you helped me find the best and simple solution:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName argonplus.by
        DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/pashas-sites/argonplus-by
        ErrorLog /home/ubuntu/pashas-sites/argonplus-by/error.log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName flowerstudio.by
        DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/pashas-sites/flowerstudio-by
        ErrorLog /home/ubuntu/pashas-sites/flowerstudio-by/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

And A-name for all sites will be the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can't specify ports in DNS records. An ANAME or CNAME record points to a server, not a specific port on a server.

If you are using a VPC (which you should be) then you could attach several network interfaces to the single server, and a different elastic IP to each interface, and then configure your web app(s) to bind to the specific IP address/network interface. There's probably a more elegant way to do that, however I don't think you really need to do any of this.

**You should be able to run multiple domains on a single IP address**, and configure Nginx or Apache to serve the correct website based on the requested domain name. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11778085/13070) as an example.