# Prestashop, Nginx and redirect

Tags: redirect, nginx, dns, prestashop-1.6

I experience the following problem:

We have two Prestashop 1.6 sites (say bar.com and bar.foo.com) running under Nginx + php-fpm. Both on the same VPS, domains with the same IP.

My bar.foo.com shop redirects me to bar.com despite different databases, shop url etc. In fact, we have other pages, which are redirected to the same bar.com, and all of them are subdomains of foo.com. Worth to mention that foo.com is running smoothly.

There are no logs errors.

Below configs of those sites as well, as a Nginx conf file.

bar.foo.com

```
server {
       listen 80;
       server_name bar.foo.com;
       root /var/www/bar.foo.com/public_html;

       if ($http_host != "bar.foo.com") {
                 rewrite ^ http://bar.foo.com$request_uri permanent;
       }

       index index.php index.html;

       location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
       }

       location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
       }

       # Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac).
       location ~ /\. {
                deny all;
                access_log off;
                log_not_found off;
       }

       rewrite ^/api/?(.*)$ /webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 last;
       rewrite ^/([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg last;
       rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg last;
       rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg last;
       rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg last;
       rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg last;
       rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg last;
       rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg last;
       rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg last;
       rewrite ^/c/([0-9]+)(\-[\.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2$3.jpg last;
       rewrite ^/c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg last;
       rewrite ^/images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ /js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 last;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
       error_page 404 /index.php?controller=404;

       location ~* \.(gif)$ {
          expires 2592000s;
       }
       location ~* \.(jpeg|jpg)$ {
          expires 2592000s;
       }
       location ~* \.(png)$ {
          expires 2592000s;
       }
       location ~* \.(css)$ {
          expires 604800s;
       }
       location ~* \.(js|jsonp)$ {
          expires 604800s;
       }
       location ~* \.(js)$ {
          expires 604800s;
       }
       location ~* \.(ico)$ {
          expires 31536000s;
       }

       location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
       }
}
```

bar.com config

```
server {

       listen bar.com:80;
       server_name *.bar.com;
       root /var/www/bar.com/public_html;

       if ($http_host != "www.bar.com") {
                 rewrite ^ http://www.bar.com$request_uri permanent;
       }

       index index.php index.html;

       location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
       }

       location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
       }

       # Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac).
       location ~ /\. {
                deny all;
                access_log off;
                log_not_found off;
       }

       rewrite ^/api/?(.*)$ /webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 last;
       rewrite ^/([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg last;
       rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg last;
       rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg last;
       rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg last;
       rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg last;
       rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg last;
       rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg last;
       rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg last;
       rewrite ^/c/([0-9]+)(\-[\.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2$3.jpg last;
       rewrite ^/c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg last;
       rewrite ^/images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ /js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 last;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
       error_page 404 /index.php?controller=404;

       location ~* \.(gif)$ {
          expires 2592000s;
       }
       location ~* \.(jpeg|jpg)$ {
          expires 2592000s;
       }
       location ~* \.(png)$ {
          expires 2592000s;
       }
       location ~* \.(css)$ {
          expires 604800s;
       }
       location ~* \.(js|jsonp)$ {
          expires 604800s;
       }
       location ~* \.(js)$ {
          expires 604800s;
       }
       location ~* \.(ico)$ {
          expires 31536000s;
       }

       location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
       }
}
```

nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    #rewrite_log on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    #error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    #error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;


    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##


    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

I would appreciate any ideas how to solve this issue.

Comment: are you sure that redirect is on Nginx side? what happened when you have empty folders like /var/www/(foo.)bar.com/public_html, is it still redirected?

Comment: Yes. I was redirected from bar.com to foo.bar.com this time

Answer (score 0):

So, there is nothing about Prestashop (just notice about title) and
to fix the issue, in bar.com conf use `listen 80;`, so there will be:

`server {
       listen 80;
       server_name .bar.com;
       root /var/www/bar.com/public_html;`

Also this page may be helpful: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: Seems that it's actually a Prestashop (theme?) problem. Same settings - two different webservices (one dummy, the second with Prestashop) and configs work fine for dummy pages, but the second webservice redirects from foo.bar.com to bar.com.

Comment: I just showed you that your Nginx config is wrong, exactly this line `listen bar.com:80;`, you can find similar Q/A here on SO e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773544/nginx-different-domains-on-same-ip