# configuring multiple domains with nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

First of all there's already a server running on 80 port(with domain, let's say domainA.com ), and I have another domain(domainB.com). Here's what I'm trying to do.

80 port: domainA.com

3000 port: domainB.com

so If I make a request to domainB.com It shouldn't redirect to `domainA.com:3000` but should actually works on the same server. and DNS server ip is set to the server as the same as domainA.com is connected to (so if I go to domainB.com it just redirects to domainA.com, I think I need to fix this part but I have no idea). how can I make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name domainA.com;
    root /var/www/domainA;
}

server {
    listen       3000;
    server_name domainB.com ;
    root /var/www/domainB;
}
```

you now can access this sites via : domainA.com and domainB.com:333
also you can make both of them listen on port 80 :
nginx can detect that request is coming for which domain and redirect request to that domain :

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name domainA.com;
    root /var/www/domainA;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name domainB.com ;
    root /var/www/domainB;
}
```

see this : [nginx server_names](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)

source : [diffrent domain on same ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773544/nginx-different-domains-on-same-ip)